# How to get the view that initiated the showing of context menu?

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have ListView, I register to listen for context menu. After that I got 3 items in the listView A,B and C. Than when I long press on some of them the context menu is show, but how can I know if that was the A or B or maybe C ? how can I find out which item was pressed ?

Comment: sorry ! , I didn't explained the problem completely ... Well the thing is that I want to show different things in the menu if is selected A (let say just view) and if selected B i want to show 'view' and 'edit'...

Answer (score 1):

you must be using some List to populate the ListView... Then use following:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    int temp = info.position;


    //temp is the index of your list.. simply use this:
    String item = list.get(temp);

    return true;
}
```

Hope it helps

**UPDATE::**

To check which item was pressed and which menu to show, see following:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    if (v.getId() == your listview id)
    {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

        //Now simply use info.position to get the string from your list. use
        // if else statements and use menu.add(String) to add menu items....           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) some examples how to work with ContextMenu, you just need to override `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)`